# Spring boot Cassandra "Error creating bean with name 'session'"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have problem with simple Spring Boot application. I'm using:

- spring-boot-starter-parent
- spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra
- Cassandra 3.11.3 (both on CentOS 7 server and local Mac OS) (query by cqlsh works)

I followed simple guide from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial and no matter if Cassandra is running or not running I 
 gets an one error while launching:

```
2018-11-25 09:12:34.581 ERROR 83213 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [some/project/path/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporte
```

My config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "packagename")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9042);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[]{"packagename"};
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Table
public class Image implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
        name = "key",
        ordinal = 0,
        type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private Blob object;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ImagesRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, UUID> {
}
```

Cassandra structure:

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    key text,
    object blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key)
);
```

Also https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-cassandra-example gives me an error on creating the bean too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [Dropwizard](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/) dependency:

> You need the metrics-core library as a dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependencies>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
>     <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
>     <version>${metrics.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Note
>
> Make sure you have a metrics.version property declared in your POM with the current version, which is 3.1.0.

Comment: Adding this dependency and changing property type `Blob` to `ByteBuffer` helped. Thank you!